# Pytest: How to reset mark.incremental for each new set of parameterized arguments

Tags: python, testing, pytest

My question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39898702/using-mark-incremental-and-metafunc-parametrize-in-a-pytest-test-class) asks about using the incremental decorator on a class that receives parametrized arguments. I described how parametrization caused the class to run the first function for each parameter, and only then the second function for each parameter, etc. I received an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47156135/5961793) of how to change the order of function calls, so that it goes function1(param1), function2(param1), function1(param2), function2(param2).

Unfortunately this did not solve the underlying problem. Using the code from the answer:

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    idlist = []
    argvalues = []
    for scenario in metafunc.cls.scenarios:
        idlist.append(scenario[0])
        items = scenario[1].items() #pretty sure this is NOT the same "item" as in function below
        argnames = [x[0] for x in items]
        argvalues.append(([x[1] for x in items]))
    metafunc.parametrize(argnames, argvalues, ids=idlist, scope="class")

def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    if "incremental" in item.keywords:
        if call.excinfo is not None:
            parent = item.parent
            parent._previousfailed = item

def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    if "incremental" in item.keywords:
        previousfailed = getattr(item.parent, "_previousfailed", None)
        if previousfailed is not None:
            pytest.xfail("previous test failed (%s)" %previousfailed.name)

# content of test_scenarios.py
import pytest

scenario1 = ('basic', {'attribute': 'value'})
scenario2 = ('advanced', {'attribute': 'value2'})

@pytest.mark.incremental
class TestSampleWithScenarios(object):
    scenarios = [scenario1, scenario2]

    def test_demo1(self, attribute):
        assert attribute=="value2"

    def test_demo2(self, attribute):
        assert isinstance(attribute, str)
```

What I get is:

test_demo1- failed

test_demo2- xfailed

test_demo1- xfailed (should be passed)

test_demo2- xfailed (should be passed)

this is because pytest is checking whether the parent has failed previously, and that doesn't rest on a new round of parameters.

Is there a way to reset the marking of the failed previously, so that incremental gives the desired report?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this @dWitty?